# Which is faster? Loop over object properties or linq query?

Tags: asp.net, linq, reflection

Is this faster

```
var query = from prop in object.GetType().GetProperties()
            where prop.Name == "Id"
            select prop;

var singleProperty = query.SingleOrDefault();
//do stuff with singleProperty
```

than this?

```
var type = object.GetType();
foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties())
{
  if(prop.Name == "Id")
   {
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

The other way around? Or are they the same?
Why and how would you know?

Sorry to be overly direct in my question.  I prefer the first one but I don't know why or if I should.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, the first case may allocate more memory and do more processing to generate the final result than the second case because of the intermediate data and LINQ abstractions.  But the amount of time and memory is so negligible in the grand scope of things, that you're way better off making your code the most readable than the most efficient for this scenario.  It's probably a case of premature optimization.

Here are some references why the first may be slightly slower:

1. http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html
2. http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test
3. http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx

Comment: But if you do not evaluate the entire IEnumerable, it could well process less data... .ToList() does this, for instance.

Comment: Makes sense. I am curious to see if there are any other views. Thanks for the input mellamokb.

Comment: @Daniel.  How would you access the name and value of the property if you don't evaluate?

Comment: First() for instance... if you only need the first property returned, you could stop there. Same as a foreach with a `break` on prop.Name=="id" though. The idea is that generators back up IEnumerable, and you need not have all elements evaluated to get at a subset of them.

Comment: @Daniel +1. I get lazy with SingleOrDefault() and ToList().

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: use Reflector to see what's being generated by the compiler.

That said, your LINQ query is using the same mechanism to retrieve the property list as your other snippet. It should technically be faster without involving the linq overhead. However, I'd expect the difference to be minimal (ie, unperceivable) , so this really comes down to a code readability and maintainability decision.

<del>And I hate LINQ, so skip it.</del>

**Retrospective, one year later**:

*I've found that LINQ isn't the demon that I thought it was. I'm actually pretty impressed with its implementation, and spent quite a bit of time looking at the IL trying to find a legitimate reason not to like it.
That said: LINQ-to-objects is pretty slick. However, future generations working on projects with a database: don't use this as a reason to perform all of your queries on the client instead of letting your database server do what it's very, very good at.*

Comment: Because cluttering up C# source with SQL-like queries feels like crappy coding.

Comment: I guess I feel the same about cluttering up code with a bunch of identically structured for/foreach loops to simply process a collection of data.  As @Reddog says, to each their own :-)

Comment: @David Lively, that is subjective, argumentative and flaming. It's irrelevant to the topic. Also, check my post here and the post from MEMark and tell me that it doesn't make it a bit more clear.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616633/sorting-selected-rows-in-datagridview/6616972#6616972

Comment: @David. Your follow up made me smile because I hate trying to look at foreach brackets.  I guess it's just a personal preference. Thanks.

Comment: @Filip flaming? I answered the question and provided a personal view on the value of a particular technique. That's hardly flaming.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same in terms of performance because LINQ makes use of [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). However, a trivially (and irrelevant) larger amount of memory may go into the LINQ option.

Therefore, they are (effectively) identical in performance and behaviour!

I would go with the LINQ version for readability because I like LINQ but to each their own.

Comment: Not to pick nits, but if the one solution requires more memory, they can't have identical performance. Allocation/deallocation, GC, etc all take time.

Comment: There is also the fact that the foreach uses a class that gets manipulated in order to iterate over the array.  Every call to that iterator class has a performance hit due using a pointer and calling a function.  Regular for loops are usually the fastest.  But if sorting is involved, linq has some neat tricks to make it faster.