# How to freeze first row when I clicked the header of column for sort in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, desktop-application, datagridviewcolumn

I have a desktop app and I am using DataGridView on form. I froze the first row. But when I clicked the header of column in DataGridView The location of the first row is also changing. How to ignore the first row while I am **sorting**.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `SortCompare` event handler for the `SortCompare` event of the `DataGridView`, try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex1 == 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The SortCompare event will not occur if the DataSource property is set

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you're asking is to be able to sort only a portion of the `DataGridView`. To my knowledge, there's no easy or standard way to do this, echoed by Filip's response to this question: [Sorting selected rows in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616633/sorting-selected-rows-in-datagridview). This doesn't mean it's impossible to achieve the behavior that you want.

Filip offers an implementation, and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012708/datagridview-selected-row-move-up-and-down), Justin offers code that you would have to modify slightly, but that may suit your needs. The question asks how to move a row up or down in a `DataGridView`, but I think you could modify his implementation to move the row you want to keep static all the way to the top after you sort. Depending on the volume of rows you're sorting, the first row might disappear and reappear. However,  if your data set is relatively small, I can't imagine the brief flash of the first row being sorted to some random position and then added back to the top would cause any major problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        int so = 1;
        if (dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            so = -1;
        }
        if (e.RowIndex1 == 0 )
        {
            e.SortResult = so;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.RowIndex2 == 0)
        {
            e.SortResult = -so;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

This code puts the first line always on top of the sorted list, by setting the sort result of the first row accordingly.